# Avoiding long compute acquisition time for sequential dataflows

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am experiencing very long compute acquisition times when running flows in sequence (7-8 minutes). I have a pipeline with several flows all running the same integration runtime with TTL = 15 minutes. It was my understanding that several flows executed one after the other and running on the same integration runtime would only incur long acquisition times for the first and not for subsequent flows, but I experience very sporadic behavior with subsequent flows sometimes spinning up very fast and other times much slower (3-8 minutes). How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using sequential data flow activity executions against the same Azure IR in the same data factory using a TTL, then you should see 1-3 minute startup times for each compute environment. If you are experiencing longer latencies, then please create a ticket on the Azure portal.  Make sure you are following the techniques described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VT_2ZV3a7Fc) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview#azure-integration-runtime-and-data-flow-strategies).